# How do I prevent multiple sessions launch for a Python program packed with py2exe?

Tags: python

I have a Python program packed with py2exe. The program runs fine, however, the user can -- intentionally or by accident -- launch a second instance (a third, etc.).

This is something not desirable, particularly because the program makes use of the serial port, so the next session will find the port busy, thus giving a port error, etc.

How can I prevent the program to launch another session once the first one has been started ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to flag if a program is running. Here are a couple of things I would do:

1) You could create a temp file in the temp folder to say I (as in the program) am running. So whenever a new instance is opened, it checks if the temp file is present in the temp folder, if it is then you throw an error saying only one instance can be open. Remember that before you exit you will have to clear the temp file.

This works only on graceful exits of the program. If the program is force closed, then the temp file may not be deleted and hence causing issues on next runs.

2) You could check the current process list to check if your program is running, and then throw an error . This would require `pywin32` module to access the process list. This requires a little more processing and adds a lot more overhead (pywin32 modules). But this is more reliable.

You could mix a combination of both, always check 1, if 1 fails check 2. Here is a sample code if you want to use `pywin32` to access the process list. You can get `pywin32` from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

```
import win32com.client
import sys

def CheckMultipleInstances():
    winmgmts = win32com.client.GetObject('winmgmts:')
    processes = winmgmts.InstancesOf('Win32_Process')
    count = 0
    for p in processes:
        if 'MyProgram.exe' == p.Properties_("Name").Value:
            count += 1
            if cound > 1:
                # This would mean that the current instance is the second one
                # raise 'Only one instance of the program can run'
                # Send a message to the user for confirmation
                # Do other code
                sys.exit()
```

[Edit] If you are using multiple threads. You will have to use `pythoncom.CoInitialize()` in your threads that use the `win32com` module.

Comment: Instead of pywin32 you could use `DETACHED_PROCESS = 8;` `out = subprocess.check_output('tasklist /fo:csv', universal_newlines=True, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS);` `processes = csv.DictReader(out.splitlines());` `process_names = [p['Image Name'] for p in processes]`.

Comment: For some reason the pywin32 method gives "moniker, i, bindCtx = pythoncom.MkParseDisplayName(Pathname)
com_error: (-2147221020, 'Invalid syntax', None, None)". Will give a try to the second (@eryksun's) method.

Comment: @secarica: hmm, I had written this code in python 3 and it worked. I just tested it with Python 2.7 as well and it seems to work. I just got the installer for pywin32 from that link above for my amd64 python 27 installation

Comment: oh! if you are using threads. You will have to coinitialize first.http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/608938-importing-wmi-child-thread-throws-error Try this.

Comment: it would be `import pythoncom` and `pythoncom.CoInitialize()` in your code

Comment: @Ashwin: yes, it was the threads issue – adding the `pythoncom.CoInitialize()` fixed it. Thank you !